# How do I run a single function with multiple threads independently?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, multiprocessing

I have the following codeblock that stores a token and uses the token in `use_token(token)`. The function calls to get a specific URL and waits for a response back.

**How do I use multithreading to call the function 50 times per thread, sequentially, using the same argument every time?**

Essentially, each thread operates independently and is responsible for calling it 50 times while waiting for the function `use_token` to respond back each time.

---

**My attempt:**

In the current example, it creates 100 threads, however it calls the function immediately 100 times. I want to run 2 threads that are responsible for running 50 threads each sequentially (call use_token function, repeat, 50 times) and not call 100 times all in one go.

```
from threading import Thread
import requests

def get_token():
    token = "test_token"
    return token

def use_token(token):
    session = requests.Session()

    data = {
        'token': token
    }

    response = session.post("https://www.examplesite.com/", data = data)


def main():
    token = get_token()

    for i in range(50):
       Thread(target = use_token, args = (token,)).start()
       Thread(target = use_token, args = (token,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to run 2 threads that are responsible for running 50 threads each sequentially"

I am a little confused by this line. I am interpreting this as "I want to run 2 threads performing 50 function calls sequentially", because sequential, to me, means it is not concurrent. Personally I like the `concurrent.futures` option in python.

```py
import time
import concurrent.futures

def get_token():
    token = "test_token"
    return token

def use_token(token):
    # time.sleep(3)
    print('Used Token')
    
def use_sequential(token, n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        use_token(token)
    
def main():
    token = get_token()
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [
            executor.submit(
                use_sequential,
                token=token,
                n=50
            ),
            executor.submit(
                use_sequential,
                token=token,
                n=50
            ),
        ]
        
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            future.result()
```

So here there are 2 threads making at most 2 concurrent `use_sequential` function calls at a time, where each thread makes 50 `use_sequential` calls. To see this running more clearly, uncomment `time.sleep(2)`. You will see 2 "Used Token" outputs come in every 3 seconds, and this will happen `n` times, so in our case 50. And thus the total number of `use_token` calls will be `n*len(futures)`.

Comment: how to handle token expired / or using refresh token in this case?